# What is a meaningfull datatype to save hours

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database-design

What is a good data-type for saving hours in .net?

Is it better to use the `decimal` type or is the `double` data-type more appropriate. With hours I mean values such as:

- 2 for two hours
- 1.5 for 90 minutes
- 8.25 for 8 hours and 15 minutes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A good way to represent a number of hours is to use a TimeSpan:

```
TimeSpan hours = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
```

Given the choice between `decimal` or `double` I'd probably go for `double` as there is typically no expectation that the amount of time is represented exactly. If you need an exact decimal representation of your fractional number of hours  (which seems unlikely) then use `decimal`.

You could also consider storing it as an integer in for example seconds, milliseconds or ticks.

Comment: +1 Thanks. And what datatype is used best to save it then in the database (Sql-Server)?

Comment: @HCL: Convert it to integer, with the necessary precision, minutes, seconds milliseconds...

Answer (score 6):

The best datatype to store hours is the one designed for it - [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

It has methods that allow you to add/subtract/convert it.

As for storage in a database, it really depends on what you are using this for and what kind of resolution is required.

I would use the [`time`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) datatype - as it will hold the range:

> 00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999

However, if you need to hold more than 24 hours in this field, you may want to consider a `tinyint` or `int` holding the number of minutes (assuming that is the maximum time resolution you require).

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server use INT or DECIMAL. TIME isn't really ideal for storing a duration because TIME defines a point in time within the 24 hour clock whereas duration is simply an integer or decimal value. You cannot do addition or subtraction with TIME values and there is no obvious way to use TIME to store durations greater than 24hrs.

Comment: I completely agree, the people suggesting TIME did not read the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use [TIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)?

You can use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) with TIME to manipulate it easier:

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, 30, CAST('2:00:00' AS TIME))
```

becomes `02:30:00.0000000`. And so on..

Comment: +1 Thanks, my initial question was about .net but additionaly, I'm also interested in this.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a great idea. TIME isn't designed for storing durations and neither are the functions that use it. I can only see disadvantages compared to using a numeric type.

Comment: @dportas: What for is it designed than, may I ask? In fact, durations.

Comment: TIME is designed for times (points in time) not durations. In your example you correctly used a number for 30 mins duration, not TIME. You can't do the same thing with a TIME value because times cannot be added and subtracted.